Identification of this component (resistor?)
In my old Commodore 128D power supply (~35 years old) I do have this component that I cannot identify. Someone else has marked it as R11, which should be a resistor, but its markings makes it impossible for me to validate it is behaving as expected.
It looks like this:

But its markings are cramped and impossible to read:

It is placed here (source link):

And the schematics, if it makes any difference for what it relates to (source link):

Measuring the Ohm then it shows 0.6 Ohm and it seems not to react on heat (so probably not a NTC/PTC resistor?).
My PSU is blowing the fuse, so I just want to validate all components on the primary/230V side of things. I do not at all expect that this component is the culprit, but I just want to know it and be sure what it is :-)
BTW: This is all originating from this thread on Lemon64 forum, C128D (plastic model) power supply problems, where I need to get this one working again.

Beauvais - Hi, Where did the PCB images come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. As a minimum, if the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). However some sources impose extra obligations e.g. copying from elsewhere on Stack Exchange must comply with the CC BY-SA license - see here for details.

Hereby added source from retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

Beauvais - Thanks. I had wondered if they were originally from elsewhere on SE. FYI that means that just adding a source link is not enough as it does not comply with the CC BY-SA license. Please read the last link in my first comment. || When you have finished doing your edits (I see you're still making changes) I will try to fix the SE reference links for you this time. || Please note for the future that SE posts are under the CC BY-SA license (currently v4.0) which means that to legitimately copy someone else's SE material, all the obligations in that license must be complied with. TY

Those PCB photos of C128 supply have been on SE before - maybe on EE.SE or RC.SE.

@Beauvais - Hi, To make sure I get the reference correct for you, I have a question: Looking at the RC.SE page you linked I think that image originally came from that OP, Ayeie Brazo, and was then edited to superimpose the component designators by Alex Hajnal who put it in their answer - and you copied it from that answer. Is that your understanding too? (FYI it matters since, if I'm correct, both of them need to be acknowledged to comply with CC BY-SA.) Please let me know if you interpret the image sources differently or the same as me. TY

I have no idea who has created the images, if this is what you ask for. I have taken it from the links I refer to, and I think it can be argued that within a reasonable doubt, I am pretty sure it originates from one of the writes in this post (for the StackExchange site).

I read 0.47 ohm in the picture, Looks OK to me. We can expect to read something around 0.6 ohm using a 2 wire measurement with a multimeter.

oh and if I remember correcty, all this thing does is give like up to 1 A of isolated 9V AC, and up to maybe 3 A of 5V – so if you need a replacement, that'd be two cheap wall warts wired up to the 5 pin commodore plug.

by the way, looking at the photo: my bets are on the bridge rectifier (GR1 "Gleichrichter"), and then on C5, and then C1…C4 being shorts. If it is GR1, chances are the rest of the primary side electronics is fried, as well.

@MarcusMüller - tested the four diodes in GR1 and seemed all fine. C1 to C8 have all been measured to be fine. TR1 however was fried, so will for sure need replacement, but I still need to test more :-)

It is a resistor. It is a high power resistor on the emitter of the main switching transistor used as a shunt for current measurement/limiting, R11 in schematics of the supply. No part number on the schematics though.
It should be rather low in value. If it reads 0.91 on it, it would be a standard E24 series value. It is unlikely to be 0.01, but multimeters do very badly on measuring sub-ohm values. You need to test what value you get with the probes shorted, and how much the resistor adds to the value, to have a reasonable estimate. It could be 0.27 too.
The place where the schematics have this means it won't be a PTC/NTC.

I think it reads "0.47", which would even be a E3-series preferred value. (Not that anyone gives a hoot about E3; if anything, about E6)
